# Position single <div> based on Screen Resolution

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am fairly new to coding and have a specific issue that I cannot figure out.  I have a container that I want positioned differently based on the screen size.  For large and mid-sized screens, I want the container left justified with a small amount of padding from the left edge, and on small screens, I want the container centered.  I am using bootstraps, html, and css.  See my style and  code below. The container is overtop of a background image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Website Name</title>
  <!-- MDB icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="img/mdb-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" />
  <!-- Google Fonts Roboto -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" />
  <!-- MDB -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdb.min.css" />
</head>

<style>
  @media (min-width: 100%) {
    #intro {
      min-width: 100%;
      margin-right: none;
      margin-top: -58.59px;
      background-color: none;
    }
  }
  
  .alfa {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: inherit;
    margin-top: 55vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: lightgrey;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-radius: 0em;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black
  }
  
  .no-pad {
    margin-right: 0rem;
    margin-left: 0rem;
  }
  
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  
  .row {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
  .main-button {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  #button1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
</style>


<body>
  <!-- Header Bar -->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">My Accounting Exec</a>

      <!--Toggle Button-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i title="" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="" style="color:white;">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="" style="color:white;">Pricing</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="" style="color:white;">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="" style="color:white;">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>



  <!-- Background-Image -->

  <container>
    <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url('../MDB5-STANDARD-UI-KIT-Free-3.5.1/img/Accountant.jpg'); height: 89vh;">
      <div class="Alert-Box text-center">
        <div class="alfa text-center;">
          <h5><b>Text Text Text</b></h5>
          <div><button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">WE ARE HERE FOR YOU!</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </container>

  <!-- Service Links -->
  <div class="row no-pad text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="border: solid .5px grey; 
                             background-color: lightgrey;
                             height: 4.5rem;
                             padding: 0;">
      </style>
      <button href="" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(210, 210, 210); height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-left: 0mm;">
                              <b>Service 1</b></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="border: solid .5px grey;
                              height: inherit; 
                              background-color: lightgrey;
                              height:4.5rem;
                              padding: 0;">
      </style>
      <button href="" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-left: 0mm;">
                               <b>Service 2</b></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="border: solid .5px grey;
                              height: inherit; 
                              background-color: lightgrey;
                              height:4.5rem;
                              padding: 0;">
      </style>
      <button href="" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(160, 160, 160); height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-left: 0mm;">
                               <b>Service 3</b></a>
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                       style="border: solid .5px grey;
                              height: inherit; 
                              background-color: lightgrey; 
                              height:4.5rem;
                              padding: 0;"></style>
                       <button href="" 
                               style="border: none; background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140); height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-left: 0mm;">
                               <b>Service 4</b></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
        <!-- End your project here-->
    
    
        <!-- MDB -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. The next time you want to include code into a question or answer, please use a stcksnippet (Ctrl+M) which can be run. Do not use `<pre>` HTML tags in any case. Last but not least, select your tags more carefully and read the description of the tag. This question has nothing to do with `visual-studio` as the question itself is not related to that IDE. Also the question has nothing to do with `basic` which is a programming language.

Comment: PS: You have an invalid HTML markup. You have multiple `</style>` closing tags inside your body which do not belong there. First you have not used any opening tag, and more importantly, `<style>` within the body is invalid HTML. There was a `scope` attribute but it was deprecated in 2014 by Chrome and 2018 by Mozilla. Sicne then it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading through all of your code, you need proper media queries that establish generalized rules and mobile only rules: ie

```
.container {
    /* CODE TO LEFT ALIGN CONTENT + padding */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        /* CODE TO CENTER CONTENT*/
    }
  }
```

That way you can have generalized rules and target specific screen size treshholds.
Hope that makes sense for you.

Comment: He is using Bootstrap, overwriting the bootstrap library is not necessary. Answers to bootstrap related questions should be solved by using bootstrap.

Comment: @tacoshy - Genuine question: isn't bootstrap effectively a superset of standard CSS?

Comment: @tacoshy fair enough. Once a bootstrap answer comes along I'll remove this answer.

Comment: @Rounin the main reason is, that margins and paddings in bootstrap can be set through classes. Therefor its not necessary to overwrite the style of all `.container` you just need to add the class for the exact margin/padding you want to add. Same for positioning.

Comment: I suspect there may be contexts in which convenience trumps necessity.